# GTK3 small font and entries on win8

Tags: python, css, gtk3

I made a GTK3 + Python3 application and packaget it with cx_freeze. When I run it on winXP the look of GtkEntry is OK, but on win8 the font and the heigth of the GtkEntry is small, as you can see on the screenshot.

[image]

I tried to change the gtk css style:

```
.entry {
    height: 25px;
}
```

But the `height` property is not supported. Also tried the `font-size` and `padding` but no success.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set `Gtk.Entry()` size directly in python?

```
SomeEntry = Gtk.Entry()<br />
SomeEntry.set_size_request(100, 25)
```

It will set width to 100 px, height to 25 px.